# ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=splashscreen.app.test.CLEARSCREEN }?

Tags: android, android-intent

i m getng this problem..basically this is a simple for creating splash screen but aftr loading splash screen i want to load main form but here m getng this problem............i hav added the activity to manifest as well....
here is my java code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logotimer=new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
            try
            {
                int timer=0;
                while(timer<5000)
                {
                    sleep(100);
                    timer=timer+100;

                }
                startActivity(new Intent("splashscreen.app.test.CLEARSCREEN"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                finish();
            }

            }
        };
        logotimer.start();

    }
}
```

and here is manifest activty i hav included

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashscreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CLEARSCREEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: How is it possible to make so many typos?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `startActivity(new Intent("splashscreen.app.test.CLEARSCREEN"));` as

```
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
```

For your information don't use Activity or class name as menu in your future.

in you manifest use,

```
<activity 
        android:name=".menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

or

```
<activity 
        android:name=".menu"/>
```

Refer this tutorial for making splashscreen http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashscreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

and:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread logotimer=new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
        try
        {
            int timer=0;
            while(timer<5000)
            {
                sleep(100);
                timer=timer+100;

            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourSplashActivityName.this,TagetActivityName.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            finish();
        }

        }
    };
    logotimer.start();

}
```

Comment: If you use the term 'menu' as your activity name then please change it to something else :) and don't forget to update the name in mainfest

Comment: bro can u tel me why this clearscreen is used in this tutorial?

Comment: and if you got my answer useful then please check the 'accept/tick' sign & upvote my answer :)